# protractor: testing bootstrap alerts

Tags: angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to Protractor testing.  Been at it for only a few hours.

I have an angular app, using bootstrap alerts.

How do I test:

- Alert (danger-alert) is not present on page load
- Alert (danger-alert) becomes present on button click
- Alert (success-alert) becomes present on another button click

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Alert (danger-alert) is not present on page load

You can use [`isPresent()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent):

```
expect(element(by.css('.alert-danger')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

Or, if the element is there but invisible, check [`isDisplayed()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed):

```
expect(element(by.css('.alert-danger')).isDisplayed()).toBe(false);
```

> Alert (danger-alert) becomes present on button click

Click the button and check if alert is there by using `isDisplayed()`:

```
element(by.id('myButton')).click()
expect(element(by.css('.alert-danger')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

> Alert (success-alert) becomes present on another button click

Same as above:

```
element(by.id('myAnotherButton')).click()
expect(element(by.css('.alert-success')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Thanks.  The clicks don't seem to be working.  Is there something I need to do special with ng-click? "<button class="submit" name="submit" ng-click="login(login.email, login.password)">Login</button>"

Comment: @Jason you can find the button by class name, e.g. `element(by.css('button.submit')).click()`.

Comment: I was doing it by name.  Here's my test, but it passes      if('should alert email missing', function() {
  element(by.name('submit')).click();
  expect(element(by.css('.alert-danger')).isPresent()).toBe(false);
});

Comment: @Jason btw, may be unrelated, what is that `if`? should not it be `it`?

Comment: That was it!  Thanks!  Too used to writing 'if' statements :)

Comment: @Jason glad it is solved. Btw, sorry for talking about it, I've noticed you haven't ever upvoted any posts but asked 68 questions. It is not required to upvote and I'm not asking about it - just see if there are answers that helped you and deserve extra points. Hope you understand! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I didn't even know about upvoting!  I just accept the answer I use.